# Passing a CheckBox or RadioButton to a method

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently I am passing my CB and RD to the following methods.

```
public void objEnabled(System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton x, bool enabled)
    {
        if (x.InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(delegate()
            {
                x.Checked = enabled;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            x.Checked = enabled;
        }
    }

    public void objEnabled(System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox x, bool enabled)
    {
        if (x.InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(delegate()
            {
                x.Checked = enabled;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            x.Checked = enabled;
        }
    }
```

But I would like to do something like the following.

```
public void objChecked(Control x, bool enabled)
    {
        if (x.InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(delegate()
            {
                x.Checked = enabled;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            x.Checked = enabled;
        }
    }
```

I am able to use something similar for changing .Text, .Visible, and .Enable. but .Checked is not part of the Controls class.

Comment: Sounds like a design-issue to me, when you are checking something like this from a background thread (thus the `BeginInvoke`).

Comment: @UweKeim This is for an automated machine interface that needs to display visual stats for the responses from an IO control board being received from a serial port received event. Never assume it is a design issue when you can not conceive every possible reason an item is used on a winform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to check the type and cast it accordingly.

```
if (x is System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton)
    (x as System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton).Checked = enabled;
else if (x is System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox)
    (x as System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox).Checked = enabled;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Checked property is not part of interface, so you can't have "common" functionality. They are defined both seperately in RadioButton and CheckBox.

If you would like to treat them as one, you can use dynamic keyword to let the runtime figure it out.

```
public void objChecked(Control x, bool enabled)
    {
        if(x as RadioButton == null && x as CheckBox == null)
          throw new Exception("Not supported");


        dynamic runtimeObject = (dynamic)x;
        if (x.InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(delegate()
            {
                runtimeObject.Checked = enabled;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            runtimeObject.Checked = enabled;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast your `control x` to the type you want: for example, `(System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton)x` will convert x from `control` to `System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton`. Then you should be able to access its checked property.

I don't think System.Windows.Forms has a base class which contains the `Checked` property, so you'll need to cast your control to a specific implementation which has `Checked`.

Answer (score 0):

Cast x as a radiobutton

```
    public void objChecked(Control c, bool enabled)
    {
        RadioButton x = c as RadioButton;
        if(x == null)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        if (x.InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(delegate()
            {
                x .Checked = enabled;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            x.Checked = enabled;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a curiosity, not recommended - other possibility without casting:

```
    public void objChecked(Control c, bool enabled)
    {
        Expression property
            = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(c), "Checked");
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action>(
                         Expression.Assign(
                             property,
                             Expression.Constant(enabled)))
                     .Compile();

         if (c.InvokeRequired)
         {
             BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(delegate()
                 {
                     lambda.Invoke();
                 }));
         }
         else
         {
             lambda.Invoke();
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Reflection.  Will work for any control with a boolean property named `Checked`.

```
delegate void MyDelegate(object control, object enabled);
public void objChecked(Control x, bool enabled)
{
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = x.GetType().GetProperty("Checked");

    if (pi != null && pi.PropertyType == System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"))
    {
        if (x.InvokeRequired)
            BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(pi.SetValue), new object[] { x, enabled });
        else
            pi.SetValue(x, enabled);
    }
}
```